# Is there any Code View for Microsoft Flow Apps?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

We can go in code view mode in Microsoft Azure Logic Apps. Is there anything same like for Microsoft flow as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no code editor for Microsoft Flow, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs). Flow Apps are built via the designer only.

You can export the Flow definition as described [here](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/grow-up-to-logic-apps/). But that is only to be imported as a Logic App, so no way to update your Flow via code.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

This will open the JSON code but you wont be able to edit it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to edit the code of an M$ Flow is to export the package to zip, and from the zip open the defintion.json. You can then repack the flow and import it back.
It's as painful as it sounds, but still easier than manually adding a dozen emails to the trigger.