# Does powerAutomate generate a code and if yes is it accessible?

Tags: powershell, power-automate

Usually, GUI-Tools produces a code in the background. This is useful if you want to reuse the script with minor changes. If this is the case which programming language does powerAutomate generate and how can I access the code?

Comment: What is GUI-Tools?

Comment: Graphical Upper Interface. It allows to work with the mouse.

Comment: So you're talking about GUI applications in general? And what kind of "code" are you referring to?

Comment: I want just to know if powerAutomate generates a code, for example, Powershell.

Comment: AFAIK PowerAutomate can run custom powershell scripts, but it's an entirely separate automation framework, it doesn't generate and execute PowerShell natively.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This is curious: automatisation without a programming language?

Comment: Power Automate _is_ the programming language - it's just a little different from other programming languages :) My understanding is that the flows in PA are compiled to .NET assemblies for portability, so the output is the same as you'd get from a C# compiler or a VB.NET compiler

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen OK, I see. This answers my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290709/is-there-any-code-view-for-microsoft-flow-apps

maybe this? I don't think you can code in Power Automate but you can view the code in JSON